# How to change axis of array slice?

Tags: numpy-ndarray

I'm fairly new to numpy arrays, so any help will be much appreciated.

I want to get a single slice of an `n x m` array along the second axis, with the result being an `n x 1` array, e.g.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6]])
```

Then I want:

```
some_function(a, 0) = array([[1], [4]])  # to get slice of a, along index 0
```

I've tried `a[:, 0]` which gives `array([1, 4])`.

And:

```
np.transpose(a[:, 0])
```

also gives:

```
array([1, 4])
```

Which confuses me.

I'm sure this is really simple but can't find the correct `some_function`!

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved it with np.reshape:

some_function(a,0) = np.reshape(a[:,0],(2,1))

But this doesn't seem too elegant. Anyone got a neater solution?